# Universal derivations in complex analytic geometry

Tags: kahler-differentials, complex-analytic-spaces

In algebraic geometry, we are used to the following universal property of K"ahler differential forms: Let $f: X \rightarrow S$ be a morphism of (Noetherian) schemes. Then there is a relative derivation $d: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \Omega^1_{X/S}$ such that, for every relative derivation $D: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ into any sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, there is a unique $\mathcal{O}_X$-linear homomorphism $h: \Omega^1_{X/S} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ such that $D = h \circ d$.

On the other hand, we also have the following explict construction: Let $\Delta: X \rightarrow X \times_S X$ be the diagonal, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the ideal sheaf of the diagonal embedding. Then we can consider $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$ as a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$, and the difference $\mathrm{pr}_2^* - \mathrm{pr}_1^*$ of the pull-backs along the two projections $X \times_S X \rightarrow X$ gives rise to a derivation $e: \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$. In particular, we have a unique homomorphism $h_{X/S}: \Omega^1_{X/S} \rightarrow \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$ with $e = h_{X/S} \circ d$. In algebraic geometry, it turns out that $h_{X/S}$ is an isomorphism.

In complex analytic geometry, we have analogs of both constructions. Let $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ be a morphism of complex analytic spaces. On the one hand, we have a universal module of K"ahler differential forms $\tilde\Omega^1_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}}$. On the other hand, we have the module of analytic differential forms $\Omega^1_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}}$, which is, according to Grothendieck's treatment in the Seminaire Cartan, constructed from the diagonal $\Delta: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X} \times_\mathcal{S} \mathcal{X}$. Again, we have a comparison map $h_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}}: \tilde\Omega^1_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}}$, but now, this map is no longer an isomorphism. Namely, the target is a coherent analytic sheaf, whereas the source is, in general, not finitely generated. The problem is that there exist too many algebraically independent convergent power series (at least I believe so).

Now results like Thm. 1.106 for finitely generated modules over analytic algebras in the book *Introduction to singularities and deformations* by Greuel--Lossen--Shustin suggest the following universal property:

Let $D: \mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ be a relative derivation with values in a coherent analytic sheaf $\mathcal{E}$. Then there is a unique homomorphism $h: \Omega^1_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ with $D = h \circ e$.

I have put quite some effort into searching a reference for this, but I could not find it. However, I don't have much knowledge about the literature on complex analytic geometry. I think that the result should be true, and probably I can prove it myself using the local result on the stalks mentioned above, but is there a place where this question already has been studied, and what is the broader reason why this should be true? I would also be interested in the case of differential operators of finite order and the analogous question for the sheaves of principal parts.

Comment: There should be a version which works for every quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal E$, where there is some sort of continuity imposed on derivations $D$.

Comment: How do you define the universal module of Kähler forms $\tilde{\Omega}^1_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}}$?

Comment: For any morphism of ringed spaces $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$, there is a universal relative derivation, see for example https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08RL Just take the induced map $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}$, then $\tilde\Omega_{\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{S}}$ is the module of differential forms defined in the reference.